# Why is the textarea value always empty when log it in a function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textarea

I’m trying to get the textarea value using JavaScript after it is rendered in the document, I used:

```
let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(input);
};
```

But it keeps on showing an empty string in the console.

Comment: You're reading the `.value` only once at startup. `input` ain't gonna update after that. You'll want to put this line into the click handler…

Answer (score 0):

Please add your HTML as well next time.

That said, in your code the value of your input is read only once when the page is loaded. If you want to read and display the updated input value you have to read it every time the button is pressed. A simple example here below:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(input);
});
```

```html
<input id="input"></input>
<button id="btn">PressMe</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use preventDefault method for solving this issue against your button event, as for some control default behavior preventing the execution of the event logic. see the solution below.Hope it will work.

```
let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(input);
})
```

Comment: This will still show the default value in the input on page load, not the value when the button was clicked. `preventDefault` doesn't change anything

Comment: Absolutely.I missed that line.Thanks for your update.