# getElementById(x).value changes the output depending on the context

Tags: javascript

I noticed that a number inserted in an number input number field used in javascript has a different value in output depending on how it is called.
In my snippet you can clearly see that calling `getElementById($number_input).value` returns always NaN in the console. If instead I assign to a variable `numb = getElementById($number_input)` and then call the value through the variable, `numb.value`, the console returns the right number.
I can't understand why javascript gives different results when both the approaches should mean the same, or at least they should to me.

Thank you in advance.

```js
const number = document.getElementById("number").value; // will not give the expected value later on
const numberCorrect = document.getElementById("number"); // will give the expected value later on
const calculateInput = document.getElementById("calculate");

calculateInput.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numb = parseInt(number);
  let numbCorrect = parseInt(numberCorrect.value);
  console.log(numb); // doesn't give the expected value: returns always NaN
  console.log(numbCorrect); // gives the expected value
})
```

```html
<h2>Number</h2>
<input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Insert a number">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the value of my input always empty if I store it in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078160/why-is-the-value-of-my-input-always-empty-if-i-store-it-in-a-variable) or [Why is the variable holding the input value always logged as empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611158/why-is-the-variable-holding-the-input-value-always-logged-as-empty) or [Why is the textarea value always empty when log it in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62085952/why-is-the-textarea-value-always-empty-when-log-it-in-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
const number = document.getElementById("number").value; // will not give the expected value later on
```

You are getting the initial value of the input, which is empty, so you are getting a `""` string.

Then, when parsing it to an integer, you get `NaN` since `""` cannot be a number

---

Instead, when doing

```
const numberCorrect = document.getElementById("number"); // will give the expected value later on
```

You are getting a reference to the input. So when you type something on it, the reference would be the same and calling `parseInt(numberCorrect.value)` would give you the current value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

"number" is the variable when the input element is created at first. So it is "NaN".

"numberCorrect" is the element.

When the value of input element is changed, "numberCorrect.value" is also changed and the "number" is not changed.

So "NaN" and current value is dispalyed.